# Mark properties with optional question mark without reordering

Tags: typescript

Look at following type declaration:

```js
type exampleType = {
  id: string;
  name: string | undefined;
  age: number;
}
```

is there any way to covert this type to looks like following:

```js
type exampleTypeConverted = Convert<exampleType>; // I want this to be equal:
{
  id: string;
  name?: string | undefined;
  age: number;
}
```

I was trying to check optional and required props (with`{ [P in keyof T]: undefined extends T[P] ? P : never }[keyof T];`), and then intersecting RequiredProps and OptionalProps into one type(`{ [P in RequiredPropNames<T>]: T[P]} & { [P in OptionalPropNames<T>]?: T[P] }`, but it makes properties reordered. Is there any way to somehow iterate thorough properties and add question mark to those which can be undefined?

EDIT: 
Ok, let me describe what I've done till now, and what results I received:

```js
type OptionalPropNames<T> = { [P in keyof T]: undefined extends T[P] ? P : never }[keyof T];
type RequiredPropNames<T> = { [P in keyof T]: undefined extends T[P] ? never : P }[keyof T];

type Converting<T> = { [P in RequiredPropNames<T>]: T[P]} & { [P in OptionalPropNames<T>]?: T[P] };
type Convert<T> = {[P in keyof Converting<T>]: Converting<T>[P]}
```

Here is what I received:

```js
type exampleTypeConverted = {
    id: string;
    age: number;
    name?: string | undefined;
}
```

The problem is that I want `name` property to be on the second position in newly created type.

Comment: I'm confused, do you have an array of "exampleType" that you want to convert to an array of "exampleTypeConverted" without reordering?

Comment: No, it's type conversion. I'll edit question to make it a little bit more clear.

Comment: Key order does not affect the structural type (e.g., `{a: string, b: number}` is precisely the same type as `{b: number, a: string}`) so the only reason you should want something like this is for aesthetics.  I also doubt such things are supposed to be exposed (it would be similar to exposing the order of constituents of a union, and that is [not supported](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298#issuecomment-468375328)), so any solution to this is likely to be ad-hoc and might break in future versions of the language.  I like this idea, though.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do (although a full code sample with your atempt would be nice to include). The problem is that if the ordering does not come from the original type itself it would have to come from some other union we create, but union ordering is not guaranteed we can't rely on it in any way. And this is not a just 'may break between versions thing', it's a 'differs between runs thing'

Comment: Ok, I hope now it's clear.

Comment: The ideal solution would be conditional statement for question mark in iterating through type properties, but as far I know it's not possible...

Comment: Nope, there is no syntax to conditionally remove the  `?` (or any other modifier) in a mapped type. You either remove them all or keep them all ..